# layout(row_major) does not affect structures

Tags: opengl, glsl

I recently discovered a strange issue. I want all my matrices to be row-major, so I  specify `layout(row_major) uniform;` once in my shaders. This works as long as the matrix is declared directly in the uniform block:

```
layout(row_major) uniform;
uniform Constants
{
    mat4 WorldViewProj; // Row-major - OK
}g_Constants;
```

BUT if `WorldViewProj` is a member of a structure, it is stored in column-major order:

```
layout(row_major) uniform;
strct Struct
{
    mat4 WorldViewProj;
};
uniform Constants
{
    Struct Str; // Now WorldViewProj is column-major!
}g_Constants;
```

On the other hand, if I additionally specify `layout(row_major)` before the block declaration, the matrix is stored correctly:

```
layout(row_major) uniform;
layout(row_major) uniform Constants
{
    Struct Str; // WorldViewProj is row-major again
}g_Constants;
```

I only see this issue on NVidia H/W, everything works fine on Intel GPUs (I did not try AMD). Is this a bug or am I again missing something in tangled OpenGL specification?

Comment: In the second example, where do you specify `row_major`? You seem to have left that off...

Comment: @SchighSchagh: I do not, because I specify `layout(row_major) uniform;` in the beginning of my program.